# Save multiple images to disk rapidly in C#

Tags: c#, image

I have a program in C# which saves a large number of images to disk after processing them
. This seems to be taking quite a bit of time due to the fact that so many images need to be saved.

Now, I was wondering: is there any way to speed up saving images in C#? At the moment, I'm using the standard [bmp.Save(filename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx) approach.

If it helps, part of the image generation process involves using lockbits to access and modify the pixel values more rapidly, so perhaps when I do this, the images could be saved to disk at the same time? Apologies if this idea is daft, but I'm still somewhat new to C#.

Comment: Have you figured out what your current save data rate is?  Is it close to the average write speed specification of the hard drive?  If it is, you can stop thinking about this.

Comment: Im not good with the Image.Save if its efficient and fast or not but I know 1 thing and that's that it all depends on your harddisk speed

Comment: Video encoders are pretty good at saving bitmaps to disk at a high rate.  There's no obvious way to give you advice beyond that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly start a new thread for each image save. That would reduce the time taken a bit, the disk would then become the bottle neck though.

One other option would be to save the images to a temporary buffer list and then return control to the program. Then have a thread to write each one to disk in the background. Of course, that would only give the appearance of this happening quickly. It could possibly serve your needs though.

I am sure that .NET has implemented some sort of Asynchronous I/O to do this for you. I know Windows has so it makes sense that it would be in .NET.

This may be helpful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: If the disk starts head-seek thrashing due to the multiple write threads, it's game over.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True, but I don't know of another option. except... I am about to update with one more sugestion. Most O.S.'s would keep the writing synchronous, but it would still be faster once they are all queued up in the write cache. Then they could write to the disk as fast as the hard drive would allow, but not have to worry about the overhead of the program iterating through each image and saving it synchronously.

Comment: Great, thanks guys : I'll take a look into this right now. Working with threads has been something I've been interested in learning, so I'll take this as an opportunity to do that right now :) Cheers!